# Can't update or install package: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: nuget

#### Problem

In a particular project, I can't update or install any NuGet packages. When I try to do so using the NuGet GUI, it does some work and then stops without saying anything. When I try to do so using the package manager console, I get this output:

```
PM> Update-Package –reinstall EntityFramework
Attempting to gather dependencies information for multiple packages with respect to project 'SmartCentre', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
Update-Package : An item with the same key has already been added.
At line:1 char:15
+ Update-Package <<<<  –reinstall EntityFramework
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UpdatePackageCommand
```

#### Environment

- Visual Studio Professional 2015 Update 1
- NuGet 3.3.0.167

#### What I've tried

- Deleting the `packages` folder
- Restarting Visual Studio
- Restarting the computer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It turned out that the `packages.config` file had a couple of duplicates with different versions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <!-- ... -->
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <!-- ... -->
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.11" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.8" targetFramework="net40" />
  <!-- ... -->
</packages>
```

Once I removed the duplicates, the problems stopped happening:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <!-- ... -->
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <!-- ... -->
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.8" targetFramework="net40" />
  <!-- ... -->
</packages>
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Two different versions of a NuGet package in a project I picked up from another developer. Checked what version was actually in use, and then removed the one not in use using Notepad. Reloaded in VS and everything worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much it has solved my problem too. Very sad to see that Microsoft could not do any better than this while reporting an issue.If it has found out that there is a duplication, i.e. key already exist. Then I don't know why it is so hard for them to tell us which key! Very sad future for them. Long live Open source.

Answer (score 6):

If any one is using net core and  got this error use command prompt to get detailed error message.

**Please run `dotnet restore`  to find the conflicting versions.**

Above command need to run form the folder where pjt file resides.

Ex:

```
 Unable to satisfy conflicting requests for '************': (>= 1.0.1)

 (via package/************ 1.0.22), ************ (>= 1.0.1)

 (via project/************ 1.0.0) Framework: 

 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)C:\Users\************\Source\************API.csproj]
```

Comment: That helped me find problem. Two different versions of System.Memory referenced by two different packages.

Comment: Thank you I almost forgot you could manually dotnet restore and get more details that way.

Answer (score 3):

The error was a duplicate proj/nuget package.  So how do you find the duplicate without removing/re-installing anything?

I ran `dotnet restore` and got a mountain of error messages. And at the very end got this:

```
C:\...\NuGet.targets(128,5): 
 error : An item with the same key has already been added.
 Key: (MyLib, 1.0.2) [C:\SomeApp.csproj]
```

`MyLib` is the duplicate.  Track down all references of it.  `SomeApp` did not reference it directly but indirectly thru another package reference.  Seems obvious now but it took me a long time just to read this line. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i have different `packages.config` files (one in pcl, one in droid and one in ios), with different package versions.
In my packages folder ( `Projects\MyProjName\packages` ), i have this situations:

[image: Some packages compare in different versions]

I removed only old versions of duplicates and after this i update data in package.config files with right version 
for example:

```
 <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.3" targetFramework="net40" />
```

became

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net40" />
```

Now you can re open project and all works fine.

Comment: Mine only had the old record and wouldn't allow an update.  So following what you did, I just changed the version after DL.  Not sure why this happened as I didn't have two. 

Thank you for the answer it helped!

Answer (score 2):

In my situation, we had a bad nuget.config file checked into our repo. It had settings pointing to two different NuGet repositories that both contained the same packages. We were using NuGet.exe 3.5. Deleting the nuget.config file fixed this issue for us.

Answer (score 2):

This error message is really extremely vague and can mean anything :(

I can recommend this approach for big projects:

- Remove all projects from your solution
- Readd them one by one until the error appears
- Check the .csproj of the project you added last

  - Delete big sections from the .csproj
  - Try if the error still exists
  - Repeat until you can narrow down the section causing the issue (readding the previously deleted sections usually is a good idea)
  - Continue until you found something that seems like a duplicate

For me it was the following in my .csproj:

```
  <RuntimeIdentifier>win</RuntimeIdentifier>
  /* Some more stuff */
  <RuntimeIdentifiers>win;linux</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

Removing `<RuntimeIdentifier>win</RuntimeIdentifier>` solved the problem.

Comment: Exactly this is what was causing issue to me

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything and then;

1. Made sure the Framework was up to date. (for the MVC package I was upgrading)
2. Uninstalled NuGet and reinstalled it.

It might be worth a try. Doesn't take too long.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow added two different versions of import references to my csproj file.  I had manually edit it to remove the extra reference.

From:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.5.0.121934\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20\Xamarin.Forms.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.5.0.121934\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" />
<Import Project="..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.1.0.583944\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.1.0.583944\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" />
```

To:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.1.0.583944\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20\Xamarin.Forms.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.1.0.583944\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" />
<Import Project="..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.v\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.1.0.583944\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" />
```

All good.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem encountered on my side. Uninstall-package followed by Install-package resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had [packaged multiple assemblies](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3959#issuecomment-333318028) in a custom NuGet package and bumped the version of the primary library, but had forgotten to update the secondary assembly.

```
My.MainPackage.dll v 1.6 <-- Bumped the version here
My.PackageDependency v 1.5 <-- Forgotten to bump this version
```

After pushing this bad package, whenever I attempted to `Update-Package` any project using the previous version, I would get the error

> An item with the same key has already been added

Since both the previous and next releases of this package both contained an old version of the secondary assembly.

The solution was simply to rebuild the broken package, bumping both assembly versions again.

FWIW any downstream projects which I had attempted to upgrade with this bad package were left in a half-baked state and needed to be manually edited to get back to a consistent version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, even **dotnet restore** didn't reveal anything.
I then did **dotnet build .sln** using VS command prompt, and it revealed the actual error along with the culprit library and the conflicting versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error while validating a new DotnetTool using NuGet Package Explorer, and the reason was that my tool was referencing code from an EXE (instead of DLL) and therefore it was ending up with two different ".deps.json" files. So it's a good idea to avoid referencing EXE files.