# Project Reference & Nuget Package Reference Conflict - Key with same name already exists

Tags: visual-studio, package, nuget, nuget-package, project-reference

Using Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.6.0 Preview 2.1 - I have a solution with two projects:

**Project A** - Has a nuget package dependency **Package1**

**Project B** - Has a project reference to **Project A**

I now also require that **Project B** include the same nuget package dependency **Package 1**

When i attempt to install the package I get an error "An item with the same key has already been added".

I have seen a few posts that discuss this, but no definitive solution. For debugging purposes I want to keep **Project A** as a project reference for **Project B**.  Any idea how I can solve for this?

Comment: What is your project type of Project A and Project B, a net framework project with `PackageReference` /`packages.config` or a net core project?

Comment: Can you install another different nuget package in Project B? Besides, could you please share the error log of failed installations? With it, we could troubleshoot this issue more quickly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Project Reference & Nuget Package Reference Conflict - Key with same
> name already exists

**First**, try to remove the Project Reference of `Project A` in `Porject B`,then Install Package in Project B and then add the Project Reference of Project A in Project B.Check if it works.

If not, I think there are some different conflicting versions of a nuget package in your Project. See [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34844765/cant-update-or-install-package-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-adde). You should remove the duplicate packages. Try these:

**1)** if you use `Packages.config`, you should check whether there are two duplicate packages like these:

```
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.11" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.8" targetFramework="net40" />
```

Delete the old one and remain the latest one. At the same time, check your `xxx.csproj` file and delete the duplicate nodes.

**2)** delete `bin`,`obj` folder of Project A and Project B

**3)** [clean local nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) and delete the **packages** folder under your solution(`xxxx\Projects\MyProjName\packages`).

After that, run `update-package -reinstall` under `Tools`-->`Nuget Package Manager`-->`Package Manager Console`.

Do both on Project A and Project B.

**4)** and then to install `Package 1` on `Project B` to test whether the issue persists.

Comment: A combination of clearing the cache and removing / resetting the project reference did the trick.  Thank You!